# Python - parsed json output to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have parsed a json file in python and have the results printed on screen.

However, I would also like the results to be output to a csv file, exactly as they appear on screen.

Here is my code:

```
import json

with open('euroinc.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    for p in d['results']:
        print(p['sedol']+','+p['company']+','+p['name']+','+ p['unitType']+','+p['perf48t60m']+','+p['perf36t48m']+','+p['perf24t36m']+','+p['perf12t24m']+','+p['perf12m']+','+p['initialCharge']+','+p['netAnnualCharge'])
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks,
Craig

Update: here is the json sample:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "sector": "Europe Including UK", 
      "perf48t60m": "n/a", 
      "discountedCode": "", 
      "price_buy": "0", 
      "plusFund": false, 
      "unitType": "Accumulation", 
      "perf6m": "6.35%", 
      "perf36t48m": "11.29%", 
      "loaded": "Unbundled", 
      "fundSize": "2940.1", 
      "annualCharge": "1.07", 
      "netAnnualCharge": "1.07", 
      "sedol": "B7BW9Y0", 
      "perf24t36m": "0.25%", 
      "annualSaving": "0.00", 
      "updated": "06/09/2017", 
      "incomeFrequency": "N/a", 
      "perf60m": "n/a", 
      "perf12t24m": "12.97%", 
      "company": "BlackRock", 
      "initialCharge": "0.00", 
      "paymentType": "Dividend", 
      "perf3m": "0.32%", 
      "name": "BlackRock Global European Value (D2 GBP)", 
      "perf12m": "19.37%", 
      "price_change": "-39.00", 
      "yield": "0.00", 
      "price_sell": "6569.00", 
      "perf36m": "35.19%", 
      "numHoldings": "51"
    }, 
    {
      "sector": "Europe Including UK", 
      "perf48t60m": "22.01%", 
      "discountedCode": "", 
      "price_buy": "0", 
      "plusFund": false, 
      "unitType": "Income", 
      "perf6m": "7.81%", 
      "perf36t48m": "9.61%", 
      "loaded": "Unbundled", 
      "fundSize": "566.1", 
      "annualCharge": "0.30", 
      "netAnnualCharge": "0.30", 
      "sedol": "B76VTR5", 
      "perf24t36m": "-3.95%", 
      "annualSaving": "0.00", 
      "updated": "06/09/2017", 
      "incomeFrequency": "Quarterly", 
      "perf60m": "77.38%", 
      "perf12t24m": "15.38%", 
      "company": "Vanguard", 
      "initialCharge": "0.00", 
      "paymentType": "Dividend", 
      "perf3m": "0.74%", 
      "name": "Vanguard SRI European Stock", 
      "perf12m": "19.69%", 
      "price_change": "-21.37", 
      "yield": "2.79", 
      "price_sell": "15800.81", 
      "perf36m": "32.65%", 
      "numHoldings": "502"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: A json sample would be much appreciated to reproduce the output!

Comment: Thanks - json added :)

Comment: A couple of entries (properly formatted) is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will write a CSV file with a header.  Note `fieldnames` and `extrasaction` parameters are required to specify the order of columns and prevent an error when there are extra dictionary entries.

```
#!python2
import json
import csv

with open('euroinc.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)

# with open('out.csv','w',newline='') as f:  # Python 3 version
with open('out.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,
                       fieldnames='sedol company name unitType perf48t60m perf36t48m perf24t36m perf12t24m perf12m initialCharge netAnnualCharge'.split(),
                       extrasaction='ignore')
    w.writeheader()
    # Ways to use a different header.
    # Note the direct write should use \r\n as that is the default 'excel' CSV dialect for line terminator.
    # f.write('A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K\r\n')
    # w.writerow(dict(zip(w.fieldnames,'col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11'.split())))
    w.writerows(d['results'])
```

Output:

```
sedol,company,name,unitType,perf48t60m,perf36t48m,perf24t36m,perf12t24m,perf12m,initialCharge,netAnnualCharge
B7BW9Y0,BlackRock,BlackRock Global European Value (D2 GBP),Accumulation,n/a,11.29%,0.25%,12.97%,19.37%,0.00,1.07
B76VTR5,Vanguard,Vanguard SRI European Stock,Income,22.01%,9.61%,-3.95%,15.38%,19.69%,0.00,0.30
```

Comment: Thank you - but its displaying this error. Am I missing something?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/craig/Documents/FundRun/Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    w.writeheader()
  File "C:\Python3\lib\csv.py", line 142, in writeheader
    self.writerow(header)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @Craig The code as written is for Python2, but has a commented out line that should be used for Python 3 instead.  What you were missing was specifying the Python version in your question :^)

Comment: Thank you Mark. Will give that a try in the morning

Comment: Oh just one quick question, can I specify the header names?

Comment: If they are different than the dictionary keys, then you can write them manually with `w.writerow(['name1','name2', ...])` instead of `w.writeheader()`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I just want the header to be different as the json doesn't really indicate the content.

I've tried this:

Comment: w.writerow(['ID','Company','Name','Type','48-60','36-48','24-36','12-24','12','Initial Cost','Net Charge'])

But it results in errors

Comment: @craig oh sorry, for a DictWriter that won't work. The rows have to be dictionaries of the field names. You'd have to write the header row manually directly to the file. I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you . Appreciate the help. I'll give it a try shortly.

Comment: Hi Mark,
Sorry to comment on an old thread. How do I remove the % characters from the CSV file that is produced? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CS10 You'd have to edit the dictionary for each row before writing.  You could use a dictionary comprehension, something like: `for item in d['results']: w.writerow({k:v.rstrip('%') if type(v) is unicode else v for k,v in item.items()})`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mark Tolonen,
When I add that, I get the following when ran:

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: @CS10 Use `str` Instead if using Python 3.

Comment: Thank you! Once again. Where would you recommend I go to read up on this and actually learn it!!?

Answer (score 0):

I assume p is a dictionary

You could try:

```
for p in d['results']:
    for key in p.keys():
        result = a[i]+',',
print result
```

for the csv part you could try:

```
import csv 
csv_file = open('your_csv.csv', 'wb') 
csv_outp = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',') 
csv_outp.writerow(result)
```

I hope this help you